# Insufficient test coverage of trigger's conditional SObject construction logic

Tags: trigger

I wrote down a trigger that create an account from a custom object Account_Setup__c. code coverage is 100%, as soon as I add the if statement, it drop down to 35%. the goal is to insert the account if approved, if rejected, don't do anything. I greatly appreciate your help,

This is my trigger in which the code is 100%

```
trigger Trigger_Noif on Account_Setup__c (After insert) {
for (Account_Setup__c B : Trigger.new) { 
   Account ac = new Account();

      ac.Name = B.Name;
      ac.industry = B.industry__c;
      ac.region__c = B.region__c;
      ac.Fax = B.Fax__c;
      ac.phone = B.Phone__c;
      ac.website = B.website__c;          
      ac.Account_Email__c = B.email__c;
      //ac.BillingAddress = B.Billing_Address__c; 
      //ac.BillingStreet = B.Billing_Street__c; 
      ac.BillingCity = B.City__c; 
      ac.BillingState = B.State__c; 
      ac.BillingPostalCode = B.Zip__c; 
      ac.BillingCountry = B.Country__c;  

      insert ac; 
 }
}
```

I added a custom field called: Status, which is a picklist data type. if I approve the account, using a workflow, the status will automatically update to "Approved", if not, it will show "Rejected".

Based on that, here is what I came up with to be able to apply that logic.

```
trigger Trigger_Update on Account_Setup__c (After insert){ 

 Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account_Setup__c.status__c.getDescribe();
 List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for (Account_Setup__c B : Trigger.new) { 
   Account ac = new Account();
    if(B.status__c == 'Approved'){       
      ac.Name = B.Name;
      ac.industry = B.industry__c;
      ac.region__c = B.region__c;
      ac.Fax = B.Fax__c;
      ac.phone = B.Phone__c;
      ac.website = B.website__c;          
      ac.Account_Email__c = B.email__c;
        //ac.BillingAddress = B.Billing_Address__c; 
        //ac.BillingStreet = B.Billing_Street__c; 
      ac.BillingCity = B.City__c; 
      ac.BillingState = B.State__c; 
      ac.BillingPostalCode = B.Zip__c; 
      ac.BillingCountry = B.Country__c;  

      //insert ac;
        }
    Else if (B.status__c == 'Rejected'){ 
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the code coverage dropped from 100% to 35%, when Salesforce requires 75%.
Can anyone help please? I am new to Apex, and still learning

thanks

Comment: Alter your test class so that it satisfy your newly introduced if statement. People can help you if you can post your test class

Comment: Please post your unit test class

Comment: I just checked,that's not the issue. I don't know if it's the code or what?

Comment: @isTest
public class Account_Creation_Class {
  static testMethod void insertNewAccountSetup() {
    Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
        B.Name = 'Name' ; 
    insert B;
    string acctId = B.Id;
  }
}

Comment: thank you all for your help. I posted the unit test class in the comment above

Comment: For your main branch to be taken, you will need to set `B.status__c = 'Approved';` in your test. This is the change mentioned in the first comment "Alter your test class so that it satisfy your newly introduced if statement".

Comment: @isTest
public class Account_creation_test{
static testMethod void insertNewAccountSetup() {
    Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
     if (B.status__c =='Approved') {
             B.Name = 'Name' ; 
             insert B;        
    }
         
     else if (B.Status__c == 'Rejected'){}
            
 }
}

Comment: My above comments contains the changes added to my unit test class. Please let me know if that's what you meant? Thanks

Comment: @Kamal No; I've posted the sort of code you need as an answer.

Comment: Keith C, thank you so much for your help, now the code coverage went back to 100%. I can't thank you enough

Comment: This should be a BEFORE trigger, as you are making changes to the record itself.

Comment: Keith, the code is back to 100%. However, there's still an issue. I applied your unit test class, when I tested my trigger, I noticed the minute I create a new account set up, the trigger automatically create an account with same info, without taking in consideration whether the account set up is approved or rejected. I only want the trigger to create an account when the custom object Account set up is approved. if it's still under "Pending" or "Rejected" status, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test needs to insert the `Account_Setup__c` object with field values that cause the trigger to enter its `if` branches:

```
@isTest
public class Account_creation_test{
    // Status of 'Approved'
    static testMethod void approved() {
        Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
        B.status__c = 'Approved';
        B.Name = 'Name' ;
        insert B;
    }
    // This is only needed if the trigger has code that runs when the status is 'Rejected'
    static testMethod void rejected() {
        Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
        B.status__c = 'Rejected';
        B.Name = 'Name' ;
        insert B;
    }
}
```

And preferably you should add more `Account_Setup__c` field values and then query the resulting `Account` and make sure that the `Account` field values are all correctly assigned too (in the test class methods).

Answer (score 0):

Try below test class

```
@isTest 
public class Account_creation_test{
   static testMethod void insertNewAccountSetup() {
     List<Account_Setup__c> insertList = new List<Account_Setup__c>();
     Account_Setup__c B = new Account_Setup__c();
     Account_Setup__c C = new Account_Setup__c();

     B.status__c =='Approved';
     B.Name = 'Name' ; 
     //set other fields as you need in trigger
    insertList.add(B); 

    C.Status__c == 'Rejected';
    C.Name = 'Another_Name';
    //set other fields

    insertList.add(C);

    insert insertList;
   }
}
```

Also change your trigger so that it becomes a bulk enabled trigger. Don't perform DMLs or queries inside loops.

```
trigger Trigger_Update on Account_Setup__c (After insert){ 

 Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account_Setup__c.status__c.getDescribe();
 List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

 List<Account> insertList = new List<Account>();

for (Account_Setup__c B : Trigger.new) { 
    Account ac = new Account();
    if(B.status__c == 'Approved'){       
      ac.Name = B.Name;
      ac.industry = B.industry__c;
      ac.region__c = B.region__c;
      ac.Fax = B.Fax__c;
      ac.phone = B.Phone__c;
      ac.website = B.website__c;          
      ac.Account_Email__c = B.email__c;
        //ac.BillingAddress = B.Billing_Address__c; 
        //ac.BillingStreet = B.Billing_Street__c; 
      ac.BillingCity = B.City__c; 
      ac.BillingState = B.State__c; 
      ac.BillingPostalCode = B.Zip__c; 
      ac.BillingCountry = B.Country__c;  

      insertList.add(ac);
    }
    Else if (B.status__c == 'Rejected'){ 
        }
    }

    if(!insertList.isEmpty())
       insert insertList;
}
```

Have a look at [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) for more information about best practices